# gradle searching jar in artifactory without version

Tags: gradle

My Gradle build has below dependency

```
|    |    +--- org.spire-math:spire_2.10:0.7.4
|    |    |    +--- org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.10.2 -> 2.10.5
|    |    |    +--- org.spire-math:spire-macros_2.10:0.7.4
|    |    |    |    +--- org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.10.2 -> 2.10.5
|    |    |    |    \--- org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:2.10.2 -> 2.10.5 (*)
|    |    |    \--- org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:2.10.2 -> 2.10.5 (*)
|    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5 -> 1.7.10
```

I get the following error on running the build

```
* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':myProject
:compileClasspath'.
> Could not find scala-reflect.jar (org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:2.10.5).
  Searched in the following locations:
      http://company_intranet:port/artifactory/vr-trunk/org/scala-lang/scala-reflect/2.10.5/scala-reflect-2.10.5.jar
```

I am not sure why the jar is searched without the version

**Could not find scala-reflect.jar**

I see that the version number is not appended to the jar

The jar with the right version is available in the artifactory

Answer (score 0):

The cache in my local machine was causing this error.

Once i used gradlew clean build -x test **--refresh-dependencies**  , it worked